# Free group over a set of two elements is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, abelian-groups, free-groups

Let $A=\{a,b\}$ and $a\ne b$. Let $F(A)$ be the free group constructed on $A$. Let $f_a,f_b$ be the canonical homomorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}$ into $F(A)$. Let $g:F(A)\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ be the unique homomorphism for which $g(f_a(1))=(1,0)$ and $g(f_b(1))=(0,1)$. Let $h:\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow F(A)$ be the mapping defined by $h(n,m)=f_a(n)f_b(m)$. Then $h\circ g=id_{F(A)}$ and $g\circ h=id_{\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}}$. This means that $g$ is an isomorphism. Since $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ is abelian, $F(A)$ is also abelian.

This is surely wrong, right? Where is the mistake?

Comment: Where do $x$ and $y$ comes from? What are the canonical homomorphisms $f_x$ and $f_y$, from what universal property do you produce them?

Comment: That was a type sorry. Fixed. I am using the free product construction.

Comment: For $h$ to be a homomorphism, you need $h(1,0)h(0,1)$ to be the same as $h(0,1)h(1,0)$, because in your domain $(1,0)+(0,1)=(0,1)+(1,0)$. That requires $ab=ba$. In short, by claiming that $h$ is a homomorphism, you are implicitly asserting your group is abelian.

Comment: Quick clarification: Doesn't isomorphism mean: homomorphism + bijection. Isn't $g$ a homomorphism and I've showed that $g$ is a bijection. No?

Comment: @panke: You have not shown that $g$ is a bijection. Your claim that the composition is the identity is incorrect, even at the set-theoretic level. For your composition to be the identity, you would need $h(g(aba))$ to equal $aba$. However, under your definition, $h(g(aba))=h(2,1) = a^2b$. You don’t know that $aba$ is the same as $a^2b$.  So again, for you to claim the composition is the identity, you need to **assume** that $ab=ba$. So you are implicitly assuming commutativity, $g$ is, in fact, not a bijection. It maps $aba^{-1}$ and $b$ to the same thing, but $aba^{-1}\neq b$ in $F$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The map $h$ is not a homomorphism.  Indeed, if you try and prove it is a homomorphism, you will find that you need to know that $f_a(1)$ and $f_b(1)$ commute in $F(A)$, which you do not know to be true (and it is in fact false).

Comment: Ah you're right. How silly.

Answer (score 2):

For $h$ to be a homomorphism, you need $h(1,0)h(0,1)$ to be the same as $h(0,1)h(1,0)$, because in your domain $(1,0)+(0,1)=(0,1)+(1,0)$. But in fact, that requires $ab=ba$, which you don’t know yet.

So your $h$ is not known to be a homomorphism. That means that your claim that $hg=\mathrm{id}$ is unjustified: it is implicitly predicated on the assumption that you have a *homomorphism* $F(A)\to F(A)$ that maps the generators to themselves identically. But because $h$ is not a homomorphism, it is not enough to check what $hg$ does to $a$ and $b$ in order to conclude the composition is the identity.

In fact, you have problems. For example, $h(g(aba)) = h(2,1) = a^2b$. So for $hg$ to be the identity, you would need $aba=a^2b$, or equivalently, $ba=ab$. That is, you need the very commutativity you are trying to prove. By asserting $hg$ is the identity, you are implicitly assuming your groups is commutative; and of course, from the assumption that $F(A)$ is commutative you can conclude that $F(A)$ is commutative...

Your $g$ is not a injective: indeed, $g(ab) = (1,1) = g(ba)$; but you don’t know that $ab=ba$. In fact, they are not equal. The kernel of $g$ consists of all products of elements of the form $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ with $x,y\in F(A)$; this is called the commutator subgroup of $F(A)$, and it is the smallest normal subgroup $N$ of $F(A)$ such that $F(A)/N$ is abelian.

Answer (score 1):

Mainly I think your maps are backwards.  Well the word "canonical" is tricky it interpret but there isn't a map $\mathbb{Z}\to F(A)$ that is unique in general, some would want $1\mapsto a$, others $1\mapsto b$, etc.  But there are maps $\hat{\pi}_a,\hat{\pi}_b:F\langle a,b\rangle\to \mathbb{Z}$.  Why? Take $\pi_a(a)=1$ and $\pi_a(a)=0$, $\pi_b(a)=0$ and $\pi_b(b)=1$.  That gives you (by the universal mapping property) the homomorphism $\hat{\pi}_a$ and $\hat{\pi}_b$.  Taken together you will make an *amalgamated* product, not a direct product.  In this case you get $F\langle a,b\rangle\to \mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$ because the kernels of $\hat{\pi}_a$ and $\hat{\pi}_b$ intersect trivially.

Answer (score 0):

The free group on two generators is not abelian.  If we have $ab=ba$,  then it is not free.  A free group satisfies no relations on its generators, hence the terminology.

Comment: This clearly doesn't answer the question, which is about spotting mistakes in a wrong "proof".